# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds while setting values of cells in JTable

Tags: java, arrays, radio-button, jtable

I'm creating a JTable from user input.  There is a selection of radio buttons in the GUI and when a one is selected it needs to update all values of a column in the table.

I'm getting an arrayIndexOutofBounds Error with this.  Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any input would be appreciated as this is my first time using a jtable and it's been harder than I figured it would be.

Code where I'm getting an error:

```
class RadioListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {                                   
        if(oneRadio.isSelected())
        {
            payAMT = payAMT * .01;
            for(int i = 1; i < outputTable.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                outputTable.setValueAt(payAMT,i,4);
            }

        }
```

Code:

```
//JTableCreation

model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Emp Num", "Base Pay", "Hours Worked", "Pay Amt"}, 0);
    outputTable = new JTable(); 
    outputTable.setModel(model);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(outputTable);
```

More Code
     //Adding Entries to JTable

```
class clickListener implements ActionListener
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int empNum = 0;
        double hourlyRate = 0;
        double hoursWorked = 0;

        try
        {
            empNum = Integer.parseInt(empNumField.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException event)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry.\n\nPlease enter a number for the Employee ID.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(basePayField.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException event)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry.\n\nPlease enter a number for the Hourly Pay Rate.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(hrsField.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException event)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid entry.\n\nPlease enter a number for the Hours Worked.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        payAMT = calculatePay(hourlyRate, hoursWorked);

        Object[] newRecord = {empNum,hourlyRate,hoursWorked,payAMT};
        model.addRow(newRecord);

        totalPayAMT += payAMT;
        totalPayLabel.setText("Total Employee Pay: "+totalPayAMT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to start your loop at index 0 instead of 1?

Comment: I tried it both ways prior to posting.  Same error.

Comment: So give us a specific scenario when this code produces that error. Does it happen when the list is empty? Does it happen when it has one element? Does it happen when there are many elements? When you stepped through your code in your debugger what relevant information did you find? Since you don't show a stacktrace, how are you sure the line of code you indicated is the problem?

Comment: When there are no entries in the JTable no error occurs.  when i = 1 the error occurs only when there are 2 or more entries in the JTable.  if i set i=0 it occurs once there are any entries in the JTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start your iteration of the JTable at 0. **Rows** and **Columns** of a JTable are 0 based. When you start your **for** loop at 1 you're not really starting at the first row like you might think, you're actually starting at row 2. Where you're also falling into confusion is with the **JTable.getRowCount()** method. This method will return the actual number of rows currently contained within your JTable so you need to adjust its value (subtract 1) in order to use it for an iteration, for example:

```
int cnt = outputTable.getRowCount();
if(oneRadio.isSelected() && cnt > 0) {
    payAMT = payAMT * .01;
    for(int i = 0; i < cnt - 1; i++) {
        outputTable.setValueAt(payAMT, i, 4);
    }
}
```